# Using $.ajax to change a list's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Looking for some help. I can't figure out why this isn't working.

I am currently trying to create ajax pagination for a list of photos. On each of the pages, I split the photos into groups of 20.

And on click of a link, I would like to replace the content within the #ajax-photos list with content on another page.

For some reason, I keep getting the error message. Even though I've used his same snippet of code in a past project and it worked great. Any know what is missing/wrong?

This what my HTML looks like.

```
<div id="ajax-photos">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/img_9583_6373616463_o-1024x683.jpg" title="" class="gallery-content-image"><img src="/img_9583_6373616463_o-540x380.jpg"></a></li>

        <li><a href="/img_9584_6373617725_o-1024x683.jpg" title="" class="gallery-content-image"><img src="/img_9584_6373617725_o-540x380.jpg"></a></li>

        <li><a href="/img_9587_6373352839_o-1024x683.jpg" title="" class="gallery-content-image"><img src="/img_9587_6373352839_o-540x380.jpg"></a></li>

        <li><a href="/img_9588_6373619113_o-1024x683.jpg" title="" class="gallery-content-image"><img src="/img_9588_6373619113_o-540x380.jpg"></a></li>

        <li><a href="/img_9589_6373620523_o-1024x683.jpg" title="" class="gallery-content-image"><img src="/img_9589_6373620523_o-540x380.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="pages">
    <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="/my-page/2/">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="/my-page/3/">3</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="/my-page/2/">»</a>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery.

```
$('.pages a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var myURI = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(myURI);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myURI,
    timeout: 2000,
    beforeSend: function(){
        
        $('#ajax-photos').prepend('<div id="loading">Test</div>');
    },
    complete: function(){
        
        $('#loading').remove();
    }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log('test');
        $('#ajax-photos').html($(data).find('#ajax-photos ul')).hide().fadeIn(400);
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Update

After running a log. I received a timeout message?

Comment: Log out the actual error instead of alerting that it didn't work.

Comment: Thought I tried that, but I guess I didn't. 

Looks like a timeout error? Can't figure out why.

Comment: @kcroake88 Don't guess, print the error and log it! Guessing is the worst when debugging.

Comment: Is the url from `$(this).attr('href')` correct? Also add a param into error callback and check what you got there - `error: function( data ){ console.dir(data); ... }`

Comment: I do have a console.log for the myURI and that seems to be correct. Looks like the data from the error log is a timeout? Which seems weird.

Comment: Figured it out... I feel like such a toolbag. Looks like the timeout: was causing an issue for some odd reason. removing that fixed it.

Comment: This should be a GET request though